VSCode "justMyCode" options doesn't work whe ntrying to debug in Python library
I am trying to get breakpoints to work inside a Python library. Everywhere I look, it says to "just enable "justmyCode": false in ./vscode/launch.json, which I did, but it did not work. The breakpoints are still clearly appearing as grey hollow circles and they do not trip when executing.
I saw here that you should be able to put it under a "python" subkey, which I did (see below), but it still doesn't work.
I am using version 1.94. I saw somewhere else that I could try downgrading to 1.89, which I tried, but then none of the python virtual environment functionality worked anymore.
I'm also using VSCode in the WSL if that makes a difference.
This is driving me crazy and it's making me seriously consider switching editors completely, can anybody help?
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {"name":"Python Debugger: Current File","type":"debugpy","request":"launch","program":"${file}","console":"integratedTerminal"},
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "general",
                "justMyCode": false,
            }
        }
    ]
}

